# BinaryReader read a list of values C#

Tags: c#, binary, binaryreader

I am trying to understand how the BinaryReader works in C#.
But how does it works for lists I would like to ask an explanation.

I am following this documentation:
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/

The documentation says that the list of mesh faces are stored in the property:

```
property list int int vertex_index
```

I believe it means that there are list of faces, where the first integer is the number of vertices per face, and other properties indicates the vertex indices. How to retrieve this list of list is my question.

Here I have the function:

```
private static DataBody ReadDataBodyBinary(DataHeader header, BinaryReader reader) {

            for (int i = 0; i < header.faceCount; i++) {
                //how can I retrieve the face list here?
            }

}
```

I tried to write inside loop:

```
int faceVertex = reader.ReadInt32();
```

But this gives me sometimes positives and sometimes negative values.

By reading the

Comment: BinaryReader can only read files in the format that BinaryWriter writes. This is not that format. Find an existing parser that can read this format, or use your own, for example using `string.Split()` and `int.TryParse()`.

Comment: Sadly there is now ply reader for C# and meshes that is opensource

Comment: What CodeCaster says is still true, you don't want to use BinaryReader to read a text file, use TextReader instead to read the file line by line and parse it as a string.

Comment: The problem is that I have a binary file that I need to read instead of .txt or ASCII file

Comment: Finally did it...

Comment: If you know the structure of your file, you should be able to read it. It's a data-first scenario. Without knowing your file-structure, you cannot read it. Binary reader is able to read everything, but you have to define how to interpret the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase someone will try to search for binary ply reader for Poisson pointcloud reconstruction using C# use this:
https://github.com/petrasvestartas/PlyReader